# On the upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^m_{i}$ subject to the conditions $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_{i}=n$

Tags: reference-request, inequalities

The following question has been posted on mathematics stackexchange: [inequalities problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913168/on-the-upper-bound-of-sum-i-1nxm-i-subject-to-the-condtions-sum-i), perhaps arising from a question on expectations.

> Let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ are real numbers, and such
> $$\begin{cases}
> x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=0\\
> x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{n}=n
> \end{cases}$$
> Let $\alpha_{m}=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^m_{i}$

See Mitrinovic D.S Analytic inequalities (Springer 1970) Page 347.

M.LAKSHMANAMURTI proved that
$$\alpha_{m}\le\dfrac{(n-1)^{m-1}+(-1)^m}{n(n-1)^{(m/2)-1}}.$$

I am interested in the details of the proof or a published reference.

[image]

Comment: Wow, there's "posti mathsatck" again. Why do you insist on writing that?

Comment: I have a feeling that people here are better at math, so I think it's going to work out here.，Thanks

Comment: Let me try again. Why do you insist on writing the incomprehensible phrase, "posti mathsatck"? "posti" is not a word. "mathsatck" is not a word. Together, they do not form a meaningful grouping of letters. So why do you keep writing them?

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in the following paper:

*Rivin, Igor*, [**Counting cycles and finite dimensional $L^{p}$ norms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0196-8858(02)00037-4), Adv. Appl. Math. 29, No. 4, 647-662 (2002). [ZBL1013.05042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1013.05042).

Comment: +1. Such a nice paper along with a slick use of the Newton's identity!

Comment: @Hans Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: You are welcome. In the proof of Theorem 6, why does $z>\sqrt{1-N_{n,p}^2}$ imply there are at most two distinct values of $x_i$? I understand that implies $z>|x_2|$. But $x_1\ge z\ge |x_2|$ holds in any case. I do not see the deduction process. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Hans I will try to get into my time machine and remember my thoughts :)

Comment: So, what secret did Giuseppe Luigi Lagrange divulge to you in your time machine? ;-)

Comment: Hi, Igor. Are you back from your trip in your time machine? :-)

Comment: @hans Not quite, but should be shortly.

Comment: Hi, Igor. Are you snoozing in Archimedes' lap?

Answer (score 1):

I have obtained a copy of the paper by Lakshmanamurti (1950); however, it appears that I cannot post a link to it here. Using Lagrange multipliers in a standard fashion, the problem is quickly reduced to the case when the cardinality (say $c$) of the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is $2$ or $3$. To deal with these two cases, pretty elaborate calculus tools are used. I think the case $c=2$ can be dealt with more efficiently, compared with the way it was done in that paper.